# Passing 'const franka::Robot' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] robot.loadModel();

Tags: c++, lambda

I am using a library provided by a robot manufacturer to read the numerical robot model and control it in real time. There are two cpp ([1](https://github.com/frankaemika/libfranka/blob/master/src/model.cpp), [2](https://github.com/frankaemika/libfranka/blob/master/src/model_library.cpp)) files and a [header](https://github.com/frankaemika/libfranka/blob/master/src/model_library.h) in order to be able to read the robot numerical model.
In one of the [examples](https://github.com/frankaemika/libfranka/blob/master/examples/generate_cartesian_velocity_motion.cpp) provided by the company, the object `robot` of the class `franka::Robot` is defined at the beginning of the `try` block. My guess is that this object is updated with the numerical robot model in the control loop (`robot.control([=, &time] ...`) every millisecond. The control loop (the loop that is being called every millisecond) is defined as a lambda function of the object robot:

```
robot.control([=, &time](const franka::RobotState& robot_state,
                         franka::Duration period) -> franka::CartesianVelocities {...}
```

In the same example, I need to be able to access the object `robot` in the control loop, in order to call the method `robot.loadModel()` and read the model. When I use `robot.loadModel();` in this loop, I will get the following error

```
Passing 'const franka::Robot' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] robot.loadModel();
```

And when I use `this.loadModel();`, I will get the error

```
'this' was not captured for this lambda function
```

I did some research about lambda functions. I think that `[=` should capture all the variables in the scope of the `main()` function, in this example. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that the object `robot` is constant and therefore, its methods can not be accessed in the control loop. Instead, we can define a static variable and call the methods inside the loop.

```
static franka::Model model(robot.loadModel());
```

Inside the control loop:

```
model.mass();
```